# Laravel can not read the user ID

Tags: mysql, laravel, vue.js, authentication

I am using laravel and vue for a project, I want to pass the user id to the table if the user is authenticated, but for some reason the authenticated user's id is not passed to the query giving this error: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'user_id' doesn't have a default value

This is laravel code for controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\Surveys; // Correct the model name
use App\Http\Requests\StoreSurveyRequest;
use App\Http\Requests\UpdateSurveyRequest;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Resources\SurveyResource;

class SurveyController extends Controller
{

public function index(Request $request)
{
    $user = $request->user();
    return SurveyResource::collection(Surveys::where('user_id', $user->id)->paginate());
}


public function store(StoreSurveyRequest $request)
{
    $result = Surveys::create($request->validated());

    return new SurveyResource($result);
}
}
```

This is the code for Request (StoreSurveyRequest):

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use App\Models\Surveys;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;
use Illuminate\Validation\Rules\Enum;

class StoreSurveyRequest extends FormRequest
{

public function authorize()
{
    return true;
}

protected function prepareForValidation()
{
    $this->merge([
        'user_id' => $this->user()->id
    ]);
}


public function rules()
{
    return [
        'title' => 'required|string|max:1000',
        'image' => 'nullable|string',
        'user_id' => 'exists:users,id',
        'status' => 'required|boolean',
        'description' => 'nullable|string',
        'expire_date' => 'nullable|date|after:tomorrow',
        'questions' => 'array',
    ];
}

}
```

Comment: Are you using sanctum? did you check if the user is authenticated before that ?

Comment: have you tried ``auth('api')->user()->id``?

Comment: Yes, only authenticated users can access this part of code.

Comment: What are you currently trying to achieve? Do you want to get a user who is already logged in? If so, you can use auth()->user()

Comment: auth('api')->user()->id not working

Answer (score 0):

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

```
$user = Auth::user();
```

please try with this method.

Comment: user_id is a foreign key in the survey table, when adding a new survey the id of currently logged in user should be stored in user_id and passed alongside other fields in the query, but somehow it is not passing the id of currently logged in user

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, all you need to do is replace this line:

```
return SurveyResource::collection(Surveys::where('user_id', $user->id)->paginate());
```

with:

```
return SurveyResource::collection(Surveys::where('user_id', auth()->user()->id)->paginate());
```

Not sure why `$user->id` is not working but the change above should do it if you have a user currently logged in.